# Proof by definition limit equals to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove by definition $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{(x-2)^3}=\infty$$

How should I approach this, if the limit is $\infty$?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{(x-2)^3}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of left- and right-handed limits?

Comment: @Surb so it is surly a mistake, but what if I had to prove by definition there is no limit?

Comment: You show that the right-handed limit is infinity, while the left-handed limit is something else (viz. negative infinity).

Comment: Do you know the definition of a limit being infinity?

Comment: No, it's not a mistake.  lim = inf by definition means sequence does not converge.  Which means by definition there is no point p that is a limit.  So proving that there is no limit *is* proving lim = inf by definition.

Comment: It is likely that you men the limit from the right, $\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{1}{(x-2)^3}$, which is actually $\infty$. The limit from the left, $\lim_{x \to 2^-} \frac{1}{(x-2)^3}$, is actually equal to $-\infty$.

Comment: @fleablood that depends on your definition.  And your definition is not a very natural one.

Comment: @mzp let assume it is the limit from left, what showed I show?

Comment: @gbox the answer below would follow analogously,  but you should instead start by assuming $-1<x-2<0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $$\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{1}{(x-2)^3}=+\infty, $$
if $0<x-2<1$, then $$(x-2)^3\leq (x-2)\implies \frac{1}{(x-2)^3}\geq \frac{1}{x-2}.$$
Then, if $M>0$, set $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{M},1\}$, to get $$\frac{1}{(x-2)^3}>M$$
when $0<x-2<\delta$ what prove the claim. I let you do the case $$\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{1}{(x-2)^3}=-\infty .$$